# Load a map from postcode using Google API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an external script to load a map and there is a button which found the exact location using the postcode. The question is how can I send from one function to another using Javascript?

The first function, where is taken the postcode is the following:

```
function findLocation(){
    var x = document.getElementById("postcode_car_park");
    getLocation();

    function getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(reverseGeoLookup);
        }
        else{
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function reverseGeoLookup(position) {
        console.log(position);
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
        req.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=true", true)
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(req.readyState == 4) {
                var result = JSON.parse(req.response).results
                for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
                    for(var j = 0; j < result[i].address_components.length; j++) {
                        var component = result[i].address_components[j]
                        //console.log(component.long_name);
                        if(~component.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
                            var out = document.getElementById('postcode_car_park');
                            out.style.display= "block";
                            out.innerHTML = "<b>" + component.long_name + "</b>";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        req.send();

    }

}
```

And the other function where I want to send the `component.long_name` from the first one is the following:

```
function automaticMap(){
    $("<script />", {
        "id":"scripting",
        "data-location":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/" + postcode,
        "data-options":"l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2",
        "data-size":"650:400",
        "src":"mapView.js",
        "type":"text/javascript"
    }).appendTo("#map")
}
```

I know that is really easy but I have been searching in the forum and I don't know how to send variables and load the map because I have used many methods and does not work. The main problem is that in the first function there are many loops and the variable is inside all of them, therefore I don't know how to access.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have `reverseGeoLookup()` simply return `component.long_name` if I understand your question correctly. Then store that value in a variable and pass it to `automaticMap()` as a parameter.

So `var component_long_name = reverseGeoLookup(position)` and then `automaticMap(component_long_name)`

Comment: In which `for` should add the `var`to send it to the other function?

Comment: I tried using after `req.onreadystatechange = function() {`and works fine but the windows appears many times. Outside that it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle that would probably help clarify.